# Help with a "hose" deformation

Tags: armature, bezier-curves, drivers, surface-deform

I'm stuck trying to bend a hose that should be attached in a sprayer bar of a tractor but I cannot find a way to bend it properly. It might be a simple thing to do but I still didn't figured out how to do it.

I tried to do it with hooks already but it doens't seem to work as intended and now I'm trying to do it with deformation vertex groups using drivers to "parent" the move of the bar and this deformation.

The thing is: it starts and end properly, but the middle animation just shrinks the very end of this hose and causes it to go out of trails.

Does someone have any idea what can be causing this bending/shrinking effect and why I can’t have it straight on the bar? I’ve tried to parent the hose to the bar but it doesn’t fix the issue.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sdq7ds99GTU

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have better chances of getting a answers if all of the information is visible in this page, instead of asking users to visit links just to understand your question. Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHwEx.png) and use the tools on the site to upload images directly. See: [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491).

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.